# How to pass variable data to view

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am facing issue while passing variable data which is defined in one function to view which is defined in index() function. I need to pass $bodystyles variable defined in bodystylelists() function to my index view with overriding initial $bodystyles. I am calling bodystylelists() through AJAX as seperate post route. How can I achieve this? Below is the controller code:

```
  class DashboardController extends Controller
 {

    public function index()
    {

        $date_lists = Salemodel::lists('Datetime');
        $makes = Saleone::distinct()->lists('Make');
        $segments = Salemodel::distinct()->lists('Segment');
        $bodystyles = Salemodel::distinct()->whereIn('segment', $segments)->lists('Bodystyle');
        $models = Salemodel::distinct()->whereIn('Bodystyle', $bodystyles)->lists('Model');

    return \View::make('analytics.dashboard.index')->with('date_lists', $date_lists)->with('segments', $segments)->with('bodystyles', $bodystyles)->with('models', $models)->with('makes', $makes);

} 

 public function bodystylelists(Request $request)
   {
        $segments = $request->input('segments');
        $bodystyles = Salemodel::distinct()->whereIn('segment', $segments)->lists('Bodystyle');
        //$bodystyles = json_encode($bodystyles);

        //print_r($bodystyles);
     }

}
```

I am implementing three filters Segment, Bodystyle, Model as a three seperate dropdownlist in my view and I am implementing them as cascading filters. i.e. when user selects any segment value then all the body styles values belonging to that particular segment should reflect in Bodystyle dropdownlist. Similar functionality needs to be implemented between Bodystyle and Model. I am populating values of these dropdownlist from MySQL database.

My sample filters are as below:

```
select Segment:1. A    select Bodystyle: 1. Hatch   select Model: 1. Alto
               2. B1                     2. Sedan                 2. Swift 
               3. C1                     3. MUV                   3. Innova
               4. C2                     4. SUV                   4. Datsun
```

Comment: Can you edit the post with your AJAX function and the part of the view that uses the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return \View::make('analytics.dashboard.index')->with(['date_lists'=> $date_lists,'segments'=> $segments,'bodystyles'=>$bodystyles,'models'=> $models,'makes'=> $makes]);
```

in blade

```
$bodystyles['Bodystyle']
```

Comment: I can pass the data to blade using {{$bodystyle}}. My issue is how can i pass the $bodystyles defined in bodystylelists() to view which is defined in index() with overriding initial $bodystyles value.

Comment: what result print_r($bodystyles);??